# What is the best html form to use to get my signout button to work via php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a signout button that I need to make work...what is the best way to do that through mysql? thanks

Comment: how do you sign in? cookie? sessions? do you keep record in the database?

Comment: Can you add some additional information? I presume this is a web app, but maybe you should confirm that, and add some language information. Are you working in PHP, perl, C#, etc.? Or are you looking for SQL to do this? If so, how do you track the session information in your DB?

Answer (score 3):

If your login system is session based and you are using PHP simply link to a php file with

```
<?php

$redirTo = 'http://www.your.domain/index.page';

session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: '.$redirTo);
exit();
```